# Fortran: Are .mod files platform dependent?

Tags: fortran

If I compile a C/C++ program and run `file my_binary` it returns something like `my_binary: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64`.

But if I run `file my_module.mod` it returns `my_module.mod: GLS_BINARY_MSB_FIRST` and I have no idea of what this means.

I know .mod files serve more or less the same functionality as .h header files except they are binary. If I copied a .mod file generated on Linux to macOS, would it work? What about different CPUs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely depends of the Fortran compiler.  In general, no you cannot simply copy a *.mod from one architecture to another.